# Unable connect to Oracle 11g using JDBC - Invalid oracle URL specified

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm struggling with establishing connection to my database using JDBC.
I've done already all necessary things mentioned in documentation.

1. I've got database working on my laptop - Oracle XE 11g rel. 2 with SID="xe", checked with SQL Developer
2. I have proper driver - ojdbc6.jar - and added it to my project in Eclipse's Java Build Path properties
3. I wrote few basic lines with try/catch block to establish connection:

   ```
       Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:xe",
               "system", "somepass");

       Statement myStat = myConn.createStatement();

       ResultSet myRe = myStat.executeQuery("SELECT * from PATIENTS");

       while(myRe.next()){
           System.out.println(myRe.getString("LAST_NAME"));
       }

       myConn.close();
       myRe.close();
   ```

But after running my code i receive error "Invalid Oracle URL specified".
Everything looks fine but I am just starting with JDBC.. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a colon - use

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
                ^
```

instead of

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:xe
               ^^^
```

as the connection string.

See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

> ... Where the URL is of the form:
>
> ```
> jdbc:oracle:<drivertype>:@<database>
> ```

Comment: What a shame.. Thank You so much!
Well, it appears that 2:00 AM is not the best time for coding :)
Cheers!

Comment: No issue - we probably all had and still have those experiences :-)

Comment: @Andreas Fester please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45284753/6303688