# how can i resolve-oracle-11g-xe using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

[image: rule for tcp port 1521]I am trying to make a sample JDBC program i which i have to create table but i am facing this issue i tried many solution present on web all i have to come to know that service is missing but did not find exact solution i am beginner in JDBC any help will be appreciated.

My JDBC program:-

```
import java.sql.*;


public class JdbcExample {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String userName="system",password="admin",url="jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:xe";
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    System.out.println(con);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    System.out.println(stmt);
    int b = stmt.executeUpdate("create table emp(eno number(5),name varchar2(20));");
    System.out.println("Table Created" + b);
    //      if(b)
    //      {
    //          
    //      }
    //      else
    //          System.out.print("WTF");


}
```

My LogCat:-

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection refused(DESCRIPTION=(TMP=)(VSNNUM=186646784)(ERR=12505)(ERROR_STACK=(ERROR=(CODE=12505)(EMFI=4))))
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:333)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:404)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at JdbcExample.main(JdbcExample.java:19)
```

My listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER = (SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = J:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
)
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = J:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
))LISTENER =(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
))DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Thanks In advance.
**NOTE : I have included ojdbc14_g.jar file in my buildconfig.**

Comment: Windows or Linux ? On Windows (all versions) check the firewall configuration and allow TCP connections to port 1521

Comment: What about through Oracle SQL Developer or TOAD?  What does a successful connection string look like in those tools?

Comment: @krokodilko i tried but resulting in same error.

Comment: Please find `listener.ora` file and append it to the question. You will find it in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` subdirectory (for example on my PC it is in `C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN`). Please also run `tnsping xe` to check conectivity to your instace.

Comment: @krokodilko please check my edited question.Thanks man for your time

Comment: `(HOST = Nicks)(PORT = 1521))` - your listener is listening on host named `Nicks` (first letter uppercase?) but not `localhost`. You must replace `localhost` with `nicks` in your connection string. Please also ping your host `ping nicks` and check if it is really configured on your machine (DNS must know it). Alternatively you can replace `nicks` with `localhost` in `listener.ora` and restart the listener.

Comment: Ping is successful and i also replaced localhost with nicks but still problem persist.how to restart listener?

Comment: `lsnrctl stop` then `lsnrctl start`. Alternatively on windows click on `Start` then click on power icon, then select `Reboot` and restart your PC.

Comment: Still getting the same error after changing nicks to localhost in my listener.ora and then restating listener

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:xe"
```

to:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your JDBC Connection string from the following:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:xe"
```

to the following:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"
```

You need to understand when to use `:` and `/`, based on the usage of SID or SERVICE NAME

```
INSTANCE SID by ":"
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID
SERVICE NAME by "/"
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/SERVICE_NAME
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @N00b Pr0grammer for your time but still it is giving me same error.

Comment: Also when i am giving url like `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE` it is showing Invaid Connection string format